VSCode on Windows stopped showing system dialogs
My VSCode does not show any Windows dialogs. It won't open "check for updates", "about" sections from help menu, it also won't allow me to use git discard command from UI, because it opens Windows popup. Every time I click on any section mentioned before - only Windows sound would play, no popup.
I am using Visual Studio Code 1.89, Windows 11. It worked just fine before I used VSCode on WSL, however I am not sure if it is WSL issue.
I have tried reinstalling VSCode, deleting all related folders, I even tried looking up the registry for Electron notifications to see if they are disabled for VSCode.
The result of running "code --verbose" in cmd
{

[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.871Z] PolicyConfiguration#initialize

[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.872Z] PolicyConfiguration#updatePolicyDefinitions [
  'http.proxy',

  'http.proxyStrictSSL',

  'http.proxyKerberosServicePrincipal',

  'http.proxyAuthorization',

  'http.proxySupport',

  'http.systemCertificates',

  'http.experimental.systemCertificatesV2',

  'telemetry.telemetryLevel',

  'telemetry.enableTelemetry',

  'update.mode',

  'update.channel',

  'update.enableWindowsBackgroundUpdates',

  'update.showReleaseNotes'
]

[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.873Z] NativePolicyService#_updatePolicyDefinitions - Found 1 policy definitions
[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.881Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Request to start watching: %\Code\User% (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>, filter: <none>, correlationId: <none>),%\Code\User\settings.json% (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>, filter: <none>, correlationId: <none>)

[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.882Z] NativePolicyService#_onDidPolicyChange - Updated policy values: {}

[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.882Z] PolicyConfiguration#update [ 'update.mode' ]

[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.887Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Started watching: 'c:\Users\anton\AppData\Roaming\Code\User'

[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.888Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Started watching: '%Code\User\settings.json%'

[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.915Z] Sending some foreground love to the running instance: 6188

[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.921Z] Sending env to running instance...

[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.979Z] Sent env to running instance. Terminating...

[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.979Z] Lifecycle#kill()

[main 2024-05-20T15:26:49.979Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown.fire()
    }


Try to start VSCODE from a command prompt (using: code --verbose) You should see a lot of lines on you screen, and VSCODE should start. Then click on one of the broken options, and see what info is added to the loggings...  Please share that as TEXT (not as IMAGE)

Please use [edit]!

Done. I cannot see any errors so far

Ok, because this is going to be off-topic, may I suggest to ask it here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues ?  (there will be more experts there anyway!)

Okay, thanks.
Here is issue link just in case if anyone else would be having same problems
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/213073

After some research I added this line to settings.json. It changes native dialogs to VSCode's ones and they work well.
"window.dialogStyle": "custom",

